# Attributes in Grouped Product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following problem in magento 1.7. I created an attribute called size_shoe multiple choice and insert it options 37, 38, 39, 40 etc. .. I configured it to use Layered Navigation on the frontend of the site.

When I create a simple product and I select some sizes, it is listed in the navigation Layers. Example: 37 (1 item) 38 (1 item)
However, when I use a grouped product it is not listed in navigation layered, but the product aparace site.
Is there any limitation of magento layered navigation does not show when using bundled products?

If yes, is there any way to make them appear?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices. One rewrite the method of how layered navigation is constructed . Basically add the children of the grouped products.  I can describe this method in more detail if desired.   The other is to add the configurable option to the grouped product and manually assign the multiple attributes.   Basically if you have the simple products of size 38 39 and 40.   Then the grouped product needs to have the multi select option of 38 39 and 40.  I have not tested this but if my memory serves me correct. This should be a good hot fix.  Here is a link to another way.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/layered-navigation-filters-for-grouped-products-only  And there are extensions that handle this as well.

Comment: Friend, thank you to passase the description of this method and I need to make changes so that it lists the grouped products.

I thank you for your help.